# JOLT transformation clone value and add default field

Tags: json, teamcity, transformation, jolt

I'm trying to create [a web populated parameter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9076-web-parameters) for [Teamcity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
Is there exist a way to perform such transformation in one jolt-specification **without external logic**?

Input:

```
{
  "version": "1",
  "servers": {
    "dev1": {
      "name": "dev1",
      "addr": "http://server1:443"
    },
    "dev2": {
      "name": "dev2",
      "addr": "http://server2:443"
    },
    "dev3": {
      "name": "dev3",
      "addr": "http://server3:443"
    },
    "dev4": {
      "name": "dev4",
      "addr": "http://server4:443"
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected** output:

```
{
  "options" : [ {
    "value" : "dev1",
    "enabled" : "true",
    "key" : "dev1"
  }, {
    "value" : "dev2",
    "enabled" : "true",
    "key" : "dev2"
  }, {
    "value" : "dev3",
    "enabled" : "true",
    "key" : "dev3"
  }, {
    "value" : "dev4",
    "enabled" : "true",
    "key" : "dev4"
  } ]
}
```

My specification with **wrong** output:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "servers": {
        "*": {
          "$0": "options.[].value",
          "name": "options.[].key",
          "#true": "options.[].enabled"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

All desired key-value pairs should be accumulated under common nodes which should be the sub-indexes of the **servers** objects in my opinion such that

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "servers": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&1.value",
          "name": "&1.key",
          "#true": "&1.enabled"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "options"
    }
  }
]
```

in the current case ( `options.[]` which's equal to `options[]` ) have no indexes nested within square bracket notations.

Comment: Thank you Barbaros for explaining your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer with one step transformation via shift by an example from [here](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/test/resources/json/shiftr/mapToList.json)

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "servers": {
        "*": {
          "$": "options[#2].value",
          "name": "options[#2].key",
          "#true": "options[#2].enabled"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```